# VBConsole - Transfer Result from Query to Batch Script and Run the batch file

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, batch-file

I have a loader to load data automatically which run using script (the loader containing the script named was `batchautoload.cmd`).

```
cd C:\file\loader\
C:\file\loader\load.exe /appID=1234 /username=admin /process="load" /initialDate=T1 /finalDate=T2
```

I have a query to determine in which there is no data loaded using above process due to failure or etc as below.

```sql
declare @initdate as varchar(20)
declare @lastdate as varchar(20)
declare @location as varchar(20)

set @initdate = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()-1);
set @lastdate = CONVERT(date,GETDATE());
set @location = 'xxxx%'

;with q(a, c) as 
(
    select MIN(date), MAX(date)
    from Table_Loader
    where nameplace like @location
    and date >= @initdate
    and date <= @lastdate
    union all
    select DATEADD(hour,1,a), c
    from q
    where a < c
)
select *
from q
where a not in
(
    select date
    from Table_Loader
    where nameplace like @location
    and date >= @initdate
    and date <= @lastdate
)
order by a asc
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
"
```

Now, my question is, is it possible to somehow transfer results from query to script where the script "/initialdate=queryresulttime /finaldate=queryresulttime+1"?

I have some general idea on using VB console, where:

1. my console will run query from DB
2. transfer result query to script (stuck in here)
3. will automatically run the script created from step #2.

Step #1

```vb
Module Module1
    Dim sqCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=10.10.111.11;Database=DataBaseMain1;Connection Timeout=50;Trusted_Connection=Yes;")
    Dim sqCmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim sdrRow As SqlClient.SqlDataReader

    Sub Main()
        sqCmd.Connection = sqCon
        sqCmd.CommandText =
            "
            declare @initdate as varchar(20)
            declare @lastdate as varchar(20)
            declare @location as varchar(20)

            set @initdate = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()-1);
            set @lastdate = CONVERT(date,GETDATE());
            set @location = 'xxxx%'

            ;with q(a, c) as 
            (
            select MIN(date), MAX(date)
            from Table_Loader
            where nameplace like @location
            and date >= @initdate
            and date <= @lastdate
            union all
            select DATEADD(hour,1,a), c
            from q
            where a < c
            )
            select *
            from q
            where a not in
            (
                select date
                from Table_Loader
                where nameplace like @location
                and date >= @initdate
                and date <= @lastdate
            )
            order by a asc
            OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
            "
        sqCon.Open()
        sqCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sdrRow = sqCmd.ExecuteReader()

        For Each itm In sdrRow 
            Dim column0 As String = sdrRow.GetValue(0)
            MsgBox(column0)
        Next

        sdrRow.Close()
        sqCon.Close()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Now I can generate the process #1 but not #2 and #3. Since the data will be used in script, I am thinking of creating temporary file of batch (appear when only this console running, deleted after the console finished process). Since I don't want to create many file from the console.

I am new in VB console thus limit my idea to get this solved. I heard about "pipe" but I do not know on how to do that. I am still thinking on continuing `For Each` loop or `For` loop, but am stuck on this. Please advise me. Just to inform, I am planning to implement this console to run on daily-basis.

Comment: Not sure what language you are using, but it sure doesn't look like VBScript.

Comment: Looks like VB.NET :) in Step #1 (and T-SQL before that)

Comment: Can you give us the bigger picture? What are you trying to do? SQL-Server *could* write batch files, but I have the feeling that the problem lies somewhere else and that there might be a better solution...

Comment: @GeertBellekens i was try using VB.net

Comment: @JayAdams I was using VB.Net, but I am not sure about the T-SQL, my DB was stored in MSSQL

Comment: @Christoph 
#1- I have a loader to automatically load data into my DB. The loader run as in .cmd file (code as shown in FirstScript)
#2- Sometimes the loader cannot load the data automatically (need to be done manually to load the data)
#3- I want to do automation for the missing timestep (since my loader run on hourly basis), by recalling the .cmd file (but the date need to use the result from query)

Comment: @Christoph The process at #2 sometimes fail due to delayed data. I am only thinking on simple process. Since i am new with this language, I dont think i cant write many more other than simple code. But i will check it on winform. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for you is to write a little winforms application that runs forever until closed and which contains a big multiline text control to log to, and a timer to check when an import is due and which calls the loader.exe to do it. (That assumes that loader.exe is a third party tool and not written by you, otherwise just implement the code to import within the same application - and also assuming that this import does not need to run unattended, otherwise a windows service would be the right choice).

The timer event waits until the process ends, and if the import is not successful sleeps 30 seconds and tries again, logging everything to screen.

Or why does step #2 fail sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

Can you adapt the export/import process like this:

- Application A exports data more or less reliably every hour and writes it into a folder resp. file share somewhere on your network, lets say `\\srvApplicationA\ExportForApplicationB`.
- Optimally application A writes it to a file with the date and time in it and a temporary extension that is renamed when finished, e.g. `Export20190530_132255.part` during the write operation and `Export20190530_132255.xml` (or whatever final extension is needed) when finished.
- Application B loops every 5 minutes through all the export files in `\\srvApplicationA\ExportForApplicationB` that have the final extension (usually none but if the service was down for some time there could be many), and for each tries to move it to folder `\\srvApplicationA\ExportForApplicationB\InProgress` and if successful, tries to import it (otherwise the error is silently ignored, the import application might have been started more than once and therefore a race condition occurred. Simply pick the next file in the loop).
- If the import succeeds, the file is move from `\\srvApplicationA\ExportForApplicationB\InProgress` to folder `\\srvApplicationA\ExportForApplicationB\Success`, if it fails to folder `\\srvApplicationA\ExportForApplicationB\Error`.
- In VB.NET you make an application, say `ImportFromAtoB.exe`, that does all the logic mentionned above and that can be started in a silent mode without user interaction.
- In VB.NET you make also a simple self-installing/deinstalling windows service, say `ImportFromAtoBService.exe` containing no logic but calling ImportFromAtoB.exe every 5 minutes (it needs to be a service as windows scheduled tasks are not reliable).
- Install the service as autostart on one of the servers or another machine that is always running and from now on the import is reliably done forever.
- This dedicated service/application setup has the advantage that you can easily debug the import logic interactivly in Visual Studio, and what I also find quite refreshing during development periods is, that one can simply copy the new import binaries over the old ones without stopping the service (that saves interactive logging on to the server through a terminal server session, stopping the service, uninstalling it, copying the files, reinstalling it, starting the service and logging off - sometimes even a reboot is needed after too many deinstalls and reinstalls of the same (modified) service).
- The only manual tasks now is to check the folder `\\srvApplicationA\ExportForApplicationB\Error` from time to time and analyze, why a certain file could not be imported (and to delete/archive the old import files in `\\srvApplicationA\ExportForApplicationB\Success` once in a while).

Comment: the process could be done. i will try it first. will let you know if its working. Thanks